# Attaching VHD at Boot Time

Tags: virtual-machines, boot

i have windows XP vmware machine , i converted it to VHD using "VmdkConvert" .

Now , I want to boot from VHD , using "Dual Boot".

Note : I use WIN 7 OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't boot into WinXP with a VHD file natively. Only Win7 has this capability.

You probably can install Virtual PC, VirtualBox, or other virtualization software and run XP as a VM.